# Issue with detecting drop inside UI panel in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a drag & drop inventory system for a game I am developing. I am using the `IDropHandler` interface for detecting drops. I am also using the `RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint()` function for seeing if the drop occurred within a UI panel.

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
     RectTransform itemPanel = transform as RectTransform;

     if (RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(itemPanel,eventData.position))
     {
          Debug.Log("dropped in box");
          AssignItem(dragDropInfo.GetDraggingItem().GetComponent<ItemPanel>().GetItemImage().GetItem());
          dragDropInfo.GetDraggingItem().GetComponent<ItemPanel>().GetItemImage().UnassignItem();
     }
}
```

This works fine for the most part. There seems to be a problem, however, related to the hierarchy of the UI. The drop is accepted and everything works as expected. When I drop it in a panel that is higher in the hierarchy (that is, one that would be rendered underneath the one I am dropping from) it stops accepting the drop and acts as I would expect if it were to drop outside a panel.

I have no clue as to why this would be case and would be very grateful for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI elements have a `Raycast Target` property which you can try disabling on elements that aren't interactable.

If that doesn't work you could also try changing it dynamically based on what you're currently dragging.